# meteor js cordova white page showing after splash screen before app load

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

The app will show white page after splash screen before load. I tried remove `mobile-experience` package, add `fastclick` and `mobile-status-bar` packages, I added `cordova-plugin-splashscreen` plugin, and set preference follow:

```
App.setPreference('SplashScreen', 'CDVSplashScreen');
App.setPreference('AutoHideSplashScreen', false);
App.setPreference('SplashScreenDelay', '30000');
```

I hide the splash screen in startup event callback:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }
});
```

But these both don't work, the white page still show ing after splash screen before app load.
Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Please note that [`Meteor.startup`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-startup) executes the given callbacks on the client (mobile app in your case) when **the DOM is ready**.

> On a client, the function will run as soon as the DOM is ready.

But there may be a small duration between DOM ready and DOM loaded / fully rendered. This is probably where your white screen appears.

You can have a search on Internet and SO to see the difference between these 2 event families:

- [`"DOMContentLoaded"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event / jQuery's [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) / `Meteor.startup()`
- [`"load"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event / jQuery's [`$(window).load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

---

Original answer:

Well, instead of hiding the launch screen on Meteor startup, you might rather be interested in your case in holding it up a little bit longer to cover that white screen…

If you can re-add the `launch-screen` package, you could simply use:

```js
// in a client-only javascript file
var handle = LaunchScreen.hold();

Template.myUI.onRendered(function () {
  handle.release();
});
```

Reference: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/launch-screen

Note that by default, the `launch-screen` package holds your splash screen until the body is fully rendered.

Comment: I removed `mobile-experience` and re-add `fastclick` `mobile-status-bar` `launch-screen`, It also not work.

Comment: As said in my above answer, it is not only a matter of packages. If you manually hide the splash screen on meteor startup, you may not give enough time to your app to render its body and load its content. You should remove your hiding and possibly hold the splash screen even longer than default.

Comment: A misconception might be in when `Meteor.startup` triggers. I will update the answer to give more details.